# ImageView disappears after LayoutParams Change

Tags: java, android, imageview, coordinates, touch-event

I added a ImageView to my LinearLayout in the onCreate method programmatically and it worked as it should.

```
    img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.source);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);
    img.setLayoutParams(params); 


  layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.index_view);
            layout.addView(img);
```

And the I want to change it's x and y coordinates when the user touches the screen.
onTouch method - case ACTION_MOVE:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(newX, newY, 0, 0);
img.setLayoutParams(params);
```

the newX and newY are calculated based on the users touch-coordinates

But this code doesn't seem to work correctly.
I created toasts to show me the Image width after every touch and it showed me that the width is set to zero after first touch. This tells me: ImageView disappeared.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you made sure that you are getting `newX, newY` values in onTouch(). 
I feel that your aim is to **edit** the Layout parameters but instead of doing that what you are doing is, you are assigning a **new** set of parameters with width and height as `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` and then setting the margins.

You might try to first get the existing parameters as follows:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
 ( LinearLayout.LayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();
```

Then change the margin:

```
params.setMargins(newX, newY, 0, 0);
img.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Try it and notify if it helps. If not then we can talk further.

Comment: I tried - but it still doesn't work. The image still disappears completely

Comment: Okay, I just noticed something very strange: If I set newX and newY to 40 (for example) it works.
Might it have something to do that negative margin is impossible? I think thats the reason

Comment: Probably your newX, newY values are always set to 0. Try to check it with your debugger.

Comment: no they aren't;
they have values between about -1000 and 1000

Comment: If suppose your screen is 200x200 and you set `newX: Left margin` and `newY: Top margin` as 100, 100, then what will happen to image? It will become of 0 size. So if your values of these 2 variables are such or greater than those, then your ImageView size might become 0. Hey just to clear: you might want to read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and then [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_marginLeft)

Comment: Oh, I see. But how can I fix this? I WANT the Image to move out of the screen

Comment: Do you want to move the image based on where you touch on screen?

Comment: No I don't. There's a more complicated mathematical formula behind that with cos & sin.<br>
But would it help if I set the Image width to standard after every setMargin()?

Comment: Oh, okay, this solution seems to work. I guess my values were just too large. I'll have to redo this calculating
Thanks for your help, it works now ;) setting the width to standard after each margin-change helps